# How do i get a connection from Oracle SQl server

Tags: java, struts, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am new to Oracle SQL Developer.

What are the connection statements for Oracle Sql Developer.

My application is a struts based application, With a simple login and register page. I want to store the data in to the DB when i register and when i login i want to check wether the user is registered or not.

```
try {
      DriverManager.registerDriver(new oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver());
      con=DriverManager.getConnection("????","user","password");
    }
catch (Exception e){
      System.out.println(e);
    }
```

I guess these are the connection statements.
What should be in the place of ????

Lemme know if am wrong.

Comment: -1, what's so hard to look this up in the Oracle manual? Or even do a simple internet search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It needs to be the JDBC connection URL pointing to your database.

```
jdbc:oracle:[driver_type]:@[server_name]:[port]:[database_name]
```

Replace the parts in brackets with their values, for example:

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:your_db
```

http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=444466